# What is difference between hex and char array print?

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf, format-specifiers

I have written following programe in `c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

char str[]="hello world";
unsigned char hexvalue[] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05};

int main()
{
    int i;

    printf("string %s \n", str);

    printf("array %x \n", hexvalue); //This line not print whole array why?

    for (i=0;i<sizeof(hexvalue);i++)
    {
        printf ("%x\n",hexvalue[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here both `str` and `hexvalue` are pointer then why they both not giving the same output when I am trying to print them?

Comment: Compile that code with warnings turned on and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case

- `printf("string %s \n", str);`

Works fine, because, `%s` expects a pointer to null-terminated `char` array, and `str` is (*or, atleast, decays to*) one.

- `printf("array %x \n", hexvalue);`

Does not work because, `%x` expects an `unsigned int` as argument, which `hexvalue` is not. Rather, it produces [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Ref: C11 standard, **§7.21.6.1**

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Also, please make a note, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: So it i change to  `unsigned char` to `unsigned int` then it work?

Comment: @Jayesh With __only__ that change, no, it will __absolutely not work__.

Comment: So i need for loop to print each value and i already done then no meaning to take `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Jayesh your best bet would be 1) change `hexvalue` to an array to `unsinged int` __and__ 2) get rid of the `printf("array %x \n", hexvalue);`

Answer (score 0):

`printf("array %x \n", hexvalue);` 
This line will not print whole array as you expect 
it'll print the address of the array 
and the address of the array is the address of the first index of the array

%x, %d otherwise is the type of the number that will shown on the console screen
in this case `printf("array %x \n", hexvalue);`
it will print the address of the array in the hex type
and if you want to print the address use %p

Answer (score 0):

The `%x` conversion specifier takes a *single* `unsigned int` as a parameter and formats the output as a hex string.  It does not expect a pointer value nor does it traverse an array of values in the same way that the `%s` conversion specifier does.

Your loop is the only way to print out the contents of the entire array (although you should use the conversion specifier `%hhx` for values of type `unsigned char`).

Answer (score -1):

The `%x` format specifier takes, as its input, an unsigned int and prints it in hex. It doesn't take a pointer to an array as you're intending.

As such, what it should print is the address of the hexvalue pointer in hex as it'll just be treating the pointer as an unsigned int.

Comment: That's not true. If the type of the argument doesn't match the format specifier, undefined behavior will occur.

Comment: Now I am racking my brain trying to figure out how one something which is "undefined" can actually "occur."

Comment: @poundifdef: "Undefined" simply means that the compiler isn't required to handle the situation in any particular way; the result could be anything from garbage output to a crash.